# Can't generate database in server explorer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've just started my first MVC 6 project in visual studio 2015.

I'm fairly new to MVC and have been working on various projects using web-forms in visual studio 2013 for the past year, but seeing as web forms is fairly outdated I decided to jump in with both feet into the newest version on MVC.

Every time I try to run the project or `dnx ef database update` I get the same error.

> The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the
>   instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow
>   remote connections

I've created all my models with entity framework (code first) and set them to the context

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        //UserModels
        public DbSet<AppUser> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserAddress> UserAddresses { get; set; }
        //Other Models...
    }
```

and set up my initial migration which all looks as it should.

I expected the database to be generated for me automatically in server explorer the first time I ran the application but I've seen that this is not something that's set up by default in MVC 6.

I've been following various tutorials and currently have in my appsettings.json

```
{
  "Data": {
    "DefaultConnection": {
      "ConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=TestDb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    }
  },
```

and startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddEntityFramework()
                .AddSqlServer()
                .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddMvc();

            // Add application services.
            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
            services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        }
```

I assume the problem is something to do with with either the way my connection string is formatted or being passed into ConfigureServices as my localDb is set to allow remote connections.

Sorry for the long winded question, but I've been banging my head off the wall for most of the day!